# Computing the volume inside a lemniscate.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Compute the volume of the lemniscate given as the graph of $x^4=x^2-y^2$.

So I thought the best way to solve this would be to take the parametrized curves, $\gamma_1(t)=(t,\sqrt{t^2-t^4})$ and the curve $\gamma_2(t)=(t,0)$ from $-1\leq t\leq 1$ and $\dot\gamma_1=(1,\frac{2t-4t^3)}{2\sqrt{t^2-t^4}})$

Then using this integral for finding the area inside a curve $\gamma_1$ I get $\int_C xdy=\int_{-1}^1 t\frac{2t-4t^3)}{2\sqrt{t^2-t^4}}dt$. But this integral seems pretty difficult to compute. So I'm not sure if there is some change of variables that would make sense here, or if I'm not computing the correct curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, because $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{t^2-2t^4}{\sqrt{t^2-t^4}} dt < 0$ (you can assume $t>0$ because the integrand is even, so $\int_{-1}^1\dots = 2 \int_0^1\dots$ and the calculation is straightforward with variables changes $t = \sqrt{z}$ and $z = 1-s$). Also $\max y = 1/\sqrt2$, but $4\int_{0}^{1/\sqrt 2} \frac{t^2-2t^4}{\sqrt{t^2-t^4}} dt$ is not the right answer: can you see why?

An easy way to calculate the area inside $x^4 = x^2 - y^2$ is the following: because the domain of integration is symmetric respect the $x$- and $y$-axis, the total area is $4 \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2-x^4} dx = 4/3$ (you can calculate this integral with the same variable changes!).